# Make line length variable to content length

Tags: html, css

I'm new, but I'll try to explain my problem as detailed as possible. I want to make a thin vertical line next to my content that begins some pixels below the slider and ends in the footer. Its length has to be variable because the content will change. I hope you can help me, if you have any questions about my problem do not hesitate asking!

Greets

Edit: Thank you for your answers so far, but I think I have to specify my dilemma. I hope it's okay if I post a link to an image here:

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3724/fws7gnd7_png.htm

This is what it should look like (the green line is my line). I am new to css and html so I don't know exactly which information you guys need. I've got an html file and a css file and I'm working with divs. Above the line should be something like a news window/tile.

Comment: If you could show us what you've done so far, it's easier to fix :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, if content is inside a div with **id="content"** then you can make this as:

```
#content{
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute:
    height: auto;
}
```

By this, you will get a vertical line beside your content and the vertical line will automatically grow along with your content.

Answer (score 1):

Say you had markup like this:

```
<header>Header</header>
<main>
    Lorem Ipsum content here
</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Simply add CSS:

```
main {
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid maroon;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/x0r68fw3/2/)** (Resize the browser to see the effect)